# How to solve Xcode Rename Error "cannot rename symbol xxx referenced by system"?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, rename

I try to rename a Swift enum case, then this message pops up. Any ideas?

"cannot rename symbol xxx referenced by system"

Xcode Version: 13.1 (13A1030d)

macOS Version: 12.1 Beta（21C5031d）

[Error Picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7l8n.png)

Comment: Can you show the code ?